# Xamarin Android - notification with app running in background

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am writing an Android app using Xamarin. I want this app to notify the user every day at a specific time. 
The notification content will be based on the result of some processing that the app will do so the app will have to run in order to notify the user correctly.

I have seen that AlarmManager can run the app at a scheduled time, which would allow my notification to work as expected. But what can I do if I want to make sure the app runs in background at a scheduled time so that the user only gets the notification without realizing that the app is running at that point?

Comment: Probably my English is not enough good, but I don't get what you mean exactly with: "so that the user only gets the notification without realizing that the app is running at that point"

Comment: Hi Mauro, I saw the solution at the link you posted. What I mean is that by scheduling an app to run at a given time, you actually see it popping up your screen like when you open the app manually. What I hope to do is to get the notification without seeing the app on the screen at all, so that the user only sees the notification and not the app itself.

Comment: So you need to see the notification without showing the activity, mmmm... I thought in that post there was exactly this.
Probably it's better if I delete the answer leaving here the url as reference:
https://nnish.com/2014/12/16/scheduled-notifications-in-android-using-alarm-manager/

Comment: Yes. There must be a way cause a lot of apps send notifications even if you don't realize that they are running.

Comment: You can use AlarmManager. App does not have to running in the background, once the the notification is schedule. See this topic. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42244217/2067264